# Why do class fields get defaulted at deserialization?

Tags: .net-core, json.net, deserialization

Hello i am having a class that is defined in a `.Net Standard` assembly.
Now i have a reference to that assembly from my `.Net Core` project.

When i try to deserialize the class in my `.Net Core` my class fields are default.

By default i mean value types get all inner values default and class fields are null.
In my example if `Val` is an `int` it would have its value `0` after deserialization whereas would it have been a `class` it would be null.

**.NET Standard** class

```
public  class Matrix
{
    public int Val { get; set; }


    public Matrix(int set) //value is default
    {
        this.Val = set;
    }
}
```

**.NET Core**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Matrix matr = new Matrix(3);


    var str=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(matr);
    var bytes=Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(str);


    var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); //string looks ok !


    var deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Matrix>(str);

}
```

Please note that my class uses a parameter in the constructor.Could this be the problem ? If my parameter constructor is indeed the problem ...how do you manage to serialize an object that needs to perform some logic in its constructor via his parameters ?

Comment: This code has several invalid and compiles time issues. For instance, `DeserializeObject` accepts a string. To make sure others can replicate your issue, can you paste the exact content from your editor/IDE? If you need to change something to hide content, make sure your simplified code compiles and replicates the issue.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say *my class fields are default*?  Do you mean that `Assert(deser.Val == matr.Val);` would fail, because `deser.Val` (which is actually a property, not a field) is zero after deserialization?  Or do you mean something else?  A [mcve] including an `Assert` statement that fails but should succeed would be ideal, and maximize the chance we can help you.

Comment: But possibly related: [Usage of non-default constructor breaks order of deserialization in Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36866131/3744182) and [Json.net `JsonConstructor` constructor parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43032552/3744182)

Comment: I am sorry that was a typo.I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Code which you provided works good. After deserialization in `deser.Val` you will see 3. But if you will change `public int Val { get; private set; }` or `public int Val { get; }` you will have a default value. For reference type it will be NULL for value type it depends.

Maybe you can provide more information and screenshot of problem?